# Run Functions on Checkbox values?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying to update results based off of how many checkboxes a user has checked on a page.

If the user has checked 5 or more then it should fade 2 divs.

If the user has checked 10 or more it should fade another two divs.

If the user chooses 10 or more it should fade another set.

I can get the first function to run but I believe since the first if statement has been completed, it's not looking for updates/value changes? The others do not fade back to 100% opacity either.

```
$('input:checkbox').change(function() {
    var boxChecked = $('input:checkbox:checked').length;
    if (boxChecked > 5) {
        $('.div-1, .div-2').fadeTo(500, 0.4)
    }
    else if (boxChecked > 10) {
        $('.div-1, .div-3').fadeTo(500, 0.4)
    }
    else if (boxChecked > 11) {
        $('.div-1, .div-2').fadeTo(500, 0.4)
    }
});
```

Comment: Are the divs supposed to cumulatively fade, or is it only for the greatest condition that is met?

Comment: The `div-3` and the `div-2` in the 2nd and 3rd `fadeTo` statements, respectively, are both missing the `.` class selector. Is this intended?

Comment: plus you want to use `boxChecked >= 5` style for all your ifs, since you said "if the user has checked 5 or more".  `boxChecked > 5` means the code won't be run unless the user has 6 or more boxes checked.

Comment: Sorry, updated the class selectors. Not sure why they were missing but were there in my js file.

Comment: @drneel once the condition is met, both of the div should fade/grey out. If there are less than 5, it should fade back.

Comment: @AoiHana both 5 and 11 are greater than 10, what should happen when 11 are checked?  Should div-1, div-2, and div-3 fade out? or just 1 and 3

Comment: @drneel Once 5 have been checked two div-2 and div 3 should fade. Once 10 divs have been checked it should fave div-1 and div 3. When 10 or more divs have been checked only div-3 should be showing while the others fade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either set ranges for your if/else statement conditions or just use if statements for your code to function correctly.

For example, if length > 5, the first branch will be taken.

However, your second branch checks if length > 10, but will never reach this statement since the first condition is also true.

You can try something like this:

```
   $('input:checkbox').change(function() {
    var boxChecked = $('input:checkbox:checked').length;
    if (boxChecked === 2) {
        $('.div-1, .div-2').fadeTo(500, 0.4);
    }
    else if (boxChecked > 3 && boxChecked <5) {
        $('.div-1, .div-3').fadeTo(500, 0.4);
    }
    else if (boxChecked > 4) {
        $('.div-1, .div-2').fadeTo(500, 0.4);
    }
    else {
        $('.div-1, .div-2, .div-3').fadeTo(500,1);
    }
});
```

Edit:  Added a jsfiddle and fixed a bug - added an else to reset the divs when conditions aren't met.
JSFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/148cL5rc/1/

Comment: Thank you for your time. This helped me a lot. I understand better now how to set these up.

Answer (score 1):

Reverse your if statements.  > 5 is always going to be true when you get above 5, so you want to start checking with the higher numbers and work your way to lower numbers.

```
$('input:checkbox').change(function() {
    var boxChecked = $('input:checkbox:checked').length;
    if (boxChecked > 11) {
        $('.div-1, .div-2').fadeTo(500, 0.4)
    } else if (boxChecked > 10) {
        $('.div-1, .div-3').fadeTo(500, 0.4)
    } else if (boxChecked > 5) {
        $('.div-1, .div-2').fadeTo(500, 0.4)
    }
});
```